# 10 gauge whip off disconnect box fed from 12/3 on 15 amp breaker for Mini Split?

Tags: electrical, wiring, mini-split

I'm wanting to make sure my shopping list is correct for my mini split install.

The mini split, Senville SENA-09HF, uses a 12/3 wire and requires a 15 amp breaker. I'm planning to buy a non-fused disconnect box and an electrical whip, but 12 gauge whips seem to be uncommon.

**Would I be safe to use a 10 gauge whip off of the disconnect box to the outdoor condenser unit?**

I could feed my own 12/3 through the conduit but first wanted to know if there's even a need to. My intuition tells me this would be fine but this wouldn't be the first time it's failed me.

Comment: If you want to pull larger wire into a conduit, you need to check conduit fill.  Your question doesn't mention conduit type, size or fill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### As long as the terminals on your mini-split accept 10AWG, you're fine

I'd go ahead and use the 10AWG whip as long as your mini-split's terminals can accept 10AWG wire (most power connections can).  If they can't, then I'd get some black and green 12AWG THHN  to replace the 10AWG the whip came with.

Answer (score 2):

[Manufacturer](https://senville.com/9000-btu-mini-split-air-conditioner-sena-09hf/) says it only uses 3.6A, the only reason to use #12 is the instructions say to. #12 is certainly adequate, #10 would be overkill. A short piece of [liquidtight](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-1-2-in-x-6-ft-Ultratite-Liquidtight-Flexible-Non-Metallic-PVC-Conduit-Whip-58004507/203369932) and some #12 THWN would certainly do the trick.